# Overwridden method won't convert

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, polymorphism, overriding

I'm given this code in order to make a runner file and I'm not sure how to define my method in the Proj05 runner class in order to print a statement before it prints the strings after declaring obj as a new Proj05Runner();

```
class Proj05{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    //Instantiate a new object of the student's class named
    // Proj05Runner. Store the object's reference in a
    // variable named obj of type Proj05.Note the 
    // difference in the type of the object and the type
    // of the variable (think inheritance).
    Proj05 obj = new Proj05Runner();
    System.out.println("==========================");
    System.out.println("Call the method named run.");
    
    //Call the instance method named run belonging to
    // the object whose reference is stored in the 
    // variable named obj.
    obj.run();
    
    //Instantiate a new object of the class named Proj05.
    // Store the object's reference in the variabler named
    // obj, overwriting the reference that was previously
    // stored there.
    obj = new Proj05();
    //Call the instance method named run belonging to
    // the object whose reference is stored in the 
    // variable named obj.
    obj.run();
     }//end main
      //----------------------------------------------------//
      void run(){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
     }//end run
}//end class Proj05
        //End program specifications.
```

This is what I have so far:

```
class Proj05Runner{
    static String run(){
        System.out.println("I certify that this program is my own work\n" +
        "and is not the work of others. I agree not\n" +
        "to share my solution with others.\n" +
        "Brendan Pitcher");
    }
}
```

but when I run Proj05, I am told that:

```
> Proj05.java:16: error: incompatible types: Proj05Runner cannot be
> converted to Proj05
>     Proj05 obj = new Proj05Runner();
>                  ^ 1 error
```

My intended output is supposed to look like:

```
I certify that this program is my own work
and is not the work of others. I agree not
to share my solution with others.
==========================
Call the method named run.
Replace this line with your name
```

edit:
I have extended Proj05 in Proj05Runner and changed the method to void run() in Proj05Runner. As a result, the program is running but displaying:

```
==========================
Call the method named run.
I certify that this program is my own work
and is not the work of others. I agree not
to share my solution with others.
Brendan Pitcher
Hello World
Press any key to continue . . .
```

as I'm still unsure of how to get the certification text to print above everything first.

Comment: It looks as though Proj05Runner should extend Proj05. Why have you made the run() method on Proj05Runner static?

Comment: *(think inheritance)* - as per the comments in the code.  `Proj05Runner` does not inherit.

Comment: @tgdavies I extended it and now it's running but I'm sure on how to get the print in Run to occur before the:
    System.out.println("==========================");
    System.out.println("Call the method named run.");

Comment: That method mustn't be static. It needs to override the `run()` method in the base class.

Comment: sorry, i already changed it to void to match the original run() in main, but i don't understand how declaring the object of Proj05Runner type is supposed to produce text before it begins printing and then calling run, redeclaring obj as Proj05 and calling run again

Comment: @Brendan I'm sorry, but I cannot understand what you want to do. "i don't understand how declaring the object of Proj05Runner type is supposed to produce text before it begins printing and then calling run, redeclaring obj as Proj05 and calling run again "

Comment: @tgdavies apologies

Comment: Perhaps if you pasted both the expected output and the actual output, plus the changed code, into the question, I might understand.

Comment: @NomadMaker the result that is intended is for the that block of text that stands as a 'certification' must appear before the lines, followed by the line that says "Call the method named run." followed by a line with my name and then it finally runs run() to write "Hello World"

Comment: Put that into the question, please.

Comment: sorry, i thought i had posted it earlier, the output is intended to be:
I certify that this program is my own work
and is not the work of others. I agree not
to share my solution with others.
==========================
Call the method named run.
Replace this line with your name

Comment: Comments aren't always read, and may be deleted by the moderators. Please paste relevant information into the question.

Comment: Posted with updates on the question, thank you.